# permission denied while uploading file to EC2

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2

I have installed apache webserver apache in linux ,I used following code to upload a file, but i get permission denied

```
scp -i adjmp.pem index.html ec2-user@ec2-50-17-88-33.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/var/www/html/hi
```

How can i upload a file to EC2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely need to change the filesystem permissions. This is usually done using the `chmod` command. You may also need to modify file ownership (using the `chown` command).

If you need help with the exact steps, you can provide the output of the following two commands and I will try to help:

```
sudo ls -al /var/www/html/hi
id
```